# Tree Grid Tube Offset

Tags: css, sass, tree, treeview, offset

I am trying to create a tube module for a tree grid. I want to keep the tube as one block and have each column as an element within the block. I would like to apply an offset to the tube so the tube below has an indent, but I'm running into an issue with the column borders lining up. How do I apply an offset to the first column of the block without applying it to the whole tube.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="m-tube">
<div class="m-tube__column">
<span class="m-tube__column--icon"></span>
<div class="m-tube__text">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
<div class="m-tube__column">
<div class="m-tube__text">Tempus Fugit</div>
</div>
<div class="m-tube__column">
<div class="m-tube__text">Fac Ut Gaudeum</div>
</div>
<div class="m-tube__column">
<div class="m-tube__text">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</div>
</div>
<div class="m-tube__column m-tube__column--no-border">
<div class="m-tube__text">Caveat Emptor</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="m-tube">
<div class="m-tube__column">
<span class="m-tube__column--icon"></span>
<div class="m-tube__text">Lorem Ipsum</div>
</div>
<div class="m-tube__column">
<div class="m-tube__text">Tempus Fugit</div>
</div>
<div class="m-tube__column">
<div class="m-tube__text">Fac Ut Gaudeum</div>
</div>
<div class="m-tube__column">
<div class="m-tube__text">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</div>
</div>
<div class="m-tube__column m-tube__column--no-border">
<div class="m-tube__text">Caveat Emptor</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the SCSS:

```
.m-tube {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  width: auto;
  height: 3.5rem;
  display: table;
  &:hover {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
  &--no-end-cap {
    border-radius: 3rem 0 0 3rem;
    border-right: 0;
  }
  &__column {
    border-right: 1px solid silver;
    padding: 0 0.5rem;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-table;
    //vertical-align: middle;
    &--no-border {
      border-right: 0;
    }
    &--icon {
      background-color: red;
      height: 1.5rem;
      width: 1.5rem;
    }
  }
  &__text {
    line-height: 3.4rem;
    color: #01527a;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
}
```